# E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout , Not duplicated nothing works ( no frame is shown)

Tags: java, android

E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout

I've seen almost a similar question like this on the site but they are kind of different problems , because in my case nothing works. I tried that solution but NO LUCK

I've clearly attached the adapter why this error is shown and in my case nothing happens , no fragment is shown

```
public class MessageFragment extends Fragment {

private RecyclerView recyclerViewMessages;
private RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState)
{ return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_messages, container, false);
}


@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    getActivity().setTitle("Messages");

    recyclerViewMessages = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerViewMessages);
    recyclerViewMessages.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerViewMessages.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));


    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(APIUrl.BASE_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();

    APIService service = retrofit.create(APIService.class);

    Call<Messages> call = service.getMessages(SharedPrefManager.getInstance(getActivity()).getUser().getId());


    call.enqueue(new Callback<Messages>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<Messages> call, Response<Messages> response) {
            adapter = new MessageAdapter(response.body().getMessages(), getActivity());
            recyclerViewMessages.setAdapter(adapter);
            Log.d("Tag","onResponse" );


        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<Messages> call, Throwable t) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), t.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    });
}
}
```

the error is (as you can see i get the error onResponse so there shouldn't be a problem with API :

```
 E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout
 D/Tag: onResponse
```

Just in case if you need to see the adapter class:

```
 public class MessageAdapter extends 
 RecyclerView.Adapter<MessageAdapter.ViewHolder> {

private List<Message> messages;
private Context mCtx;

public MessageAdapter(List<Message> messages, Context mCtx) {
    this.messages = messages;
    this.mCtx = mCtx;
}

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.list_messages, parent, false);
    return new ViewHolder(v);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MessageAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    final Message message = messages.get(position);
    holder.textViewName.setText(message.getFrom());
    holder.textViewTitle.setText(message.getTitle());
    holder.textViewMessage.setText(message.getMessage());
    holder.textViewTime.setText(message.getSent());
}


@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return messages.size();
}


public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    public TextView textViewName;
    public TextView textViewTitle;
    public TextView textViewMessage;
    public TextView textViewTime;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        textViewName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewName);
        textViewTitle = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewTitle);
        textViewMessage = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewMessage);
        textViewTime = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewTime);
    }
}
}
```

Is it possible that the problem could be caused because of something else (another part of the program?

Comment: You'll get the `No adapter attached` message when the `RecyclerView` gets laid out before an `Adapter` has been set. That's to be expected with your setup, because that Retrofit call is asynchronous, and it won't complete before the first layout. You need to inspect the results to see what you're getting. It seems like you're probably not getting what you expect.

Comment: Read the @MikeM. comment. I just add the tip to set an empty adapter when you initialize the RecyclerView, and update the adapter when the async call is completed.

Comment: set Adapter first ....call notifyDatasetChanged() after api call from ui thread

Comment: Thank you @MikeM. it worked

Comment: Thanks @PembaTamang it did work

Comment: Thank you @GabrieleMariotti . followed your instructions and it did work

Comment: learn coroutines it will help you with this kind of work